# D3 LinearGradient broken in Chrome when using groups

Tags: google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I have being using LinearGradient on IE9/IE11 where everything work fine but as soon as I test the sample on chrome found that the linearGradient is not being rendered, managed to reproduced the issue when I wrap the shape that use the LinearGradient on a group 
Working version with not groups http://jsfiddle.net/v3127wmp/1

```
var width = 300,  height = 300;
var svg = d3.select('#div').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
//var g = svg.selectAll('g').append('g');


var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient").attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%").attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "100%").attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

 gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#a00000").attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#aaaa00").attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var gradient2 = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient").attr("id", "gradient2")
    .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%").attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "100%").attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

 gradient2.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#a00000").attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient2.append("stop").attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#aaaa00").attr("stop-opacity", 1);


var circle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', width / 2)
    .attr('cy', height / 2)
    .attr('r', height / 3)
    .attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)');
```

Broken version with groups http://jsfiddle.net/u1zs2oqo

```
    var width = 300,  height = 300;
var svg = d3.select('#div').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
var g = svg.selectAll('g').append('g');


var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient").attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%").attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "100%").attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

 gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#a00000").attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("stop").attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#aaaa00").attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var gradient2 = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient").attr("id", "gradient2")
    .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%").attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "100%").attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

 gradient2.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#a00000").attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient2.append("stop").attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#aaaa00").attr("stop-opacity", 1);


var circle = g.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', width / 2)
    .attr('cy', height / 2)
    .attr('r', height / 3)
    .attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Chrome issue.  It is an issue with your script.

If you look at the actual SVG generated in the "groups" example you will see the following result:

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" ... >
  </defs>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient2" ... >
  </defs>
</svg>
```

So there is no `<g>` and no `<circle>`.  So there is something wrong with your script.

Comment: The error is: `var g = svg.selectAll('g').append('g');`. The selectAll method will not find any g elements until they've been inserted into the document. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll.